# Node js Mysql Connection Pooling using with Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling, node-mysql

Here is the mysql.js file

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    connectTimeout: 5000,
    acquireTimeout: 5000,
    queueLimit: 30,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: '',
    multipleStatements: true,
});


var getConnection = function(callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(err, connection);
    });
};

pool.on('acquire', function(connection) {
    console.log('Connection %d acquired', connection.threadId);
});
module.exports = getConnection;
```

Here is the my one of the route controller

```
var getConnection = require('../config/mysql');
//get / or /homepage 
exports.getIndex = function(req, res) {
    getConnection(function(err, con) {
        que = 'SELECT SOMETHING FROM SOMEWHERE';
        con.query(que, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            //console.log(result[0]);
            con.release();
            res.render('page/home', { result:result});
        });
    })
}
```

I use the controller in my routes.js file like this

```
var controller = require('../controllers/indexController');
router.get('/', controller.getIndex);
```

My question is about connection pooling. Is my way good to use connection pooling? And also I use this way other controllers, so I mean if I need a connection in controller I call the connection for each controller. Thanks for advice